# ForEach with index in C#

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'm need to call function from `ForEach` in Linq, and I need to send a string parameter and the Index from the `ForEach`

```
List<string> listString= new List<string>();

listString.ForEach((str, i) => { Func(str, i) , i++});

private ResponseBase Func(string s,int i)
{
```

Comment: ForEach is *not* a part of LinQ, so I'll remove that tag.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of LINQ. Really.

But in this cases, when you are accessing an already existing `List`, I would go for an old fashioned for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < listString.Count; i++)
    Func(listString[i], i);
```

It's not longer, it's far more efficient (it's probably not a problem, but let's remember this), and it just gets the job done.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
var responses = listString.Select((value, index) => Func(value, index)).ToList();
```

The above for each item in `listString` would call the method you have defined. The results of all calls would be stored in a list and you could access them by using the corresponding index.

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce a variable and then increment it:

```
List<String> values = new List<String>();
int indexTracker = 0;
values.ForEach(x=> { Func(x, indexTracker++); });
```

Or you can write the following extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this List<T> input, Action<T, int> action)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        action(input[i], i);
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
values.ForEach((x,i)=> Func(x, i));
```